# Can PostgreSQL have md5 auth for 1 IP range and certificate authentication for another IP range?

Tags: postgresql-11, postgresql-12

I saw that in pg_hba.conf , we have the option to set different authentication for different IPs .  Like can we set password (md5) authentication for 1 IP Range and certificate authentication for another IP range.
Please help.
Please share any good links for examples of implementing

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes possible. I tried myself and it worked.